# What are the possible causes for "This has been disabled" message in a WordPress site?

Tags: php, wordpress, apache, dns, http-status-code-403

I have a WordPress multisite installation and many sites working fine there. But I have created a new one now and there is a little big problem.

On this new site, first of all, I have to say there is no problem to access all the external content. And I can do a logon on admin area without problems. But, on admin area, if I try to access anything, I'm redirected to the page (because the URL changes) but I can't see the content, just a white box where that says "**This has been disabled**". Then I do a new logon and I can see the page I wanted to access. But when I try to click on anything, "This has been disabled" message again and again.

There is no error on debug but there is one in console:

```
GET <the URL I tried to access> 403 (Forbidden)
```

I think that's not a theme/plugin problem at all. Maybe a wrong configuration on multisite, Apache or DNS. I don't know. I'm lost.

Comment: Is the url for the same resource of a request that succeeds exactly the same as the request that fails? Using your browser's network tools compare the cookies of a request that fails with the corresponding request that succeeds.

Comment: Yes, it's the same. And, OK, I will compare the cookies. Besides that I noticed that the logoff doesn't happen. If I click in the browser to back to the previous screen, I'm in admin area again. And if I try to access the same link where I had the problem, it will work. But on the next click the problem will happen again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved that cleaning Chrome DNS cache:

```
chrome://net-internals/#dns
```